# is there a shell command to insert a string of characters in every line of a file

Tags: file, shell

is there any shell command to insert a string of characters in every line of a file..
< in the beginning or the end of every line >

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of them.

This will work:

```
sed -i -e 's/.*/START & END/' file
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked.. Will I be able to insert line number specific variable in every line < like in line i , can i insert i-1 >

Comment: You can print the current line number in sed with the '=' command, though it is followed by a \n and I don't recall atm how to get rid of that (short of filtering everything through a second sed, which is ugly). I'll post another answer which tells you how to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i 's/^/Before/' file.txt
sed -i 's/$/After/'  file.txt
```

Comment: This will also work (though results go to stdout rather than to a file).

Comment: @profjim, no: the `-i` flag is present. Note that the `-e` flag is optional if there's only one script block to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
linecount=0
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
  echo "$((linecount++)) START $LINE END"
done < file
```

If you want to do fancier manipulation of the linecount:

```
linecount=0
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
  let linecount++
  echo "$((linecount-5)) START $LINE END"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk '{print NR"START"$0"END"}' file
```